# How to define multiline long_description in quickly's setup.py?

Tags: application-development, quickly

When I try using triple quotes `python-mkdebian` crashes loudly with apport appearing after `quickly package [--extras]` and when I just make multiline string in single quotes the latter stops silently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator to join strings. Here's an extract of how I do it in the `setup.py` file of my app:

```
long_description="Qreator enables you to easily create your " +
                 "own QR codes to encode different types of information " +
                 "in an efficient, compact and cool way.",
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Python's [implicit line continuation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) like this:

```
long_description=(
    "Qreator enables you to easily create your "
    "own QR codes to encode different types of information "
    "in an efficient, compact and cool way."
),
```